# cvs editors does not work from many places in the same project

Tags: version-control, cvs

I am using `cvs` for a project. I check out a copy of the project from the repository using `cvs checkout ...` and then use `cvs edit <file>` for editing them. Now, consider the sample directory structure for my project below:

```
project/:

dir1/:
sample1.C

dir2/:
sample2.C
```

Now assume that I run the following commands:

```
cd ~/cvs/project/dir1/
cvs edit sample1.C
cd ../dir2
cvs edit sample2.C
cvs editors
```

My output will contain only `sample2.C` and no mention of `sample1.C`. If I `cd` into `dir1` I can see only `sample1.C` as being edited. My questions are as follows:

1. Is there something wrong with my `cvs` settings? Or should I invoke the `cvs edit` command from a single place for whatever file I need to edit in order to see all the files being edited in one place.
2. Is there a command in `cvs` which I can use to see all the files being edited in `cvs` across projects?

P.S: Please let me know in case more details are needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cvs` commands by default work on the current directory and below. So in your example, because you are in `dir2`, you are only see `sample2.C`. If you moved back up to the `proect` directory you would see both files.